# TimeSeries scale in ChartJS 3.0.2. brings error "This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was ..."

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I upgraded to the newest Chart.JS version 3.0.2. and I'm trying to get a time series chart to render. Here is my config:

```
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: dataForChart
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have imported the module like this:

```
import ChartJS from 'chart.js/auto';
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was provided.
```

Any tips on what I could be making wrong?

Here is a code sandbox with that problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cdn-j6q2u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you ever solve this? None of the answers provided work

Answer (score 57):

You need to install and import an adapter, in your case it's moment adapter for time series

`npm install moment chartjs-adapter-moment --save`

then import it in your component:
`import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';`

for more info about adapters, check [this](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters)

Answer (score 20):

This answer comes a bit late but for everyone who stumbles here: You need a date adapter. Find a [full list here](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome)

Once you installed i.e. date-fns via `npm install date-fns chartjs-adapter-date-fns --save` in your root directory you have to do two things to make it work in your React project:

1. Add this at the top of your file `import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';` and `import { enUS } from 'date-fns/locale';`
2. Inside your options:

```js
options = {
  ... 
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',

      // add this: 
      adapters: { 
        date: {
          locale: enUS, 
        },
      }, 
    }
  },
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for compiling all configuration in one place.

Answer (score 17):

You need an adaptor as stated above. Look here: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns#cdn

One option is to add the following cdn links:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in your error and the documentation you need an adapter to convert the dates to date objects, see documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put list in x like below code.

```
scales: {
  x: [{
    type: 'time'
  }]
}
```

Comment: This wont fix the issue, this is the correct way to specify the x axis as a time axis in V2, in V2 a date adapter was already provided by chart.js but since he is getting that error he is using v3. In v3 there is no date adapter and library shipped by default and scale config has changed. So this wont fix the issue, only thing that this does is make the x axis a category scale again