# Canvas chart how to display xAxis time format

Tags: angular, canvas, charts

I'm trying to display a time linear graph in Angular 14 with `chart.js` version `3.9.1`.
I've been trying a lot of examples from https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ or youtube tutorials and I couldn't find something to work. Below you can see what I wanted to achieve and the code that is not working. Any help or idea will be very helpful.

The yAxis is `number` and xAxis is `DateTime`.

TS file

```
data: ChartData = {
  labels: [new Date('2021-11-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-12-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2022-01-16T00:00:00')],
  datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      data: [2, 3, 1],
      label: 'Title',
      fill: true,
    }],
};

options: ChartOptions = {
  plugins: {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart.js Time Scale',
      display: true
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        tooltipFormat: 'DD T'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Date'
      }
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'value'
      }
    }
  },
};
```

HTML file

```
<canvas baseChart style="height: 20em;"
        type="line"
        [data]="data"
        [options]="options">
</canvas>
```

**Expected behavior:** to see something like this [image]

**Actual behavior:** displays nothing

Comment: AS I tried to dig further for a solution, I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409070/9459066

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is the code you are feeding to `new Chart`
just have a couple syntax issues...

first, don't need the name assignment here...

these...

```
data: ChartData = {

options: ChartOptions = {
```

should be...

```
data: {

options: {
```

and the reason nothing is displayed is because of the semi-colon at the end,
it should be a comma,
here...

```
data: ChartData = {
  labels: [new Date('2021-11-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-12-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2022-01-16T00:00:00')],
  datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      data: [2, 3, 1],
      label: 'Title',
      fill: true,
    }],
};        <<--- change to comma (,)
```

corrected...

```
data: {
  labels: [new Date('2021-11-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-12-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2022-01-16T00:00:00')],
  datasets: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [2, 3, 1],
    label: 'Title',
    fill: true,
  }]
},
options: {
  plugins: {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart.js Time Scale',
      display: true
    }
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        tooltipFormat: 'DD T'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Date'
      }
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

see following working snippett...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [new Date('2021-11-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-12-16T00:00:00'), new Date('2022-01-16T00:00:00')],
      datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        data: [2, 3, 1],
        label: 'Title',
        fill: true,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        title: {
          text: 'Chart.js Time Scale',
          display: true
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            tooltipFormat: 'DD T'
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Date'
          }
        },
        y: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'value'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```